# Как указать количество страниц для парсинга, если мне не известно?

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет!
Написал функцию-парсер, который получает данные с 10 ссылок (и в каждой ссылке ходит по страницам, но мне неизвестна максимальная страница, да и в каждой ссылке может находится различное количество страниц.

Как быть? Я в этом деле новичок.. Буду признателен за ответ!

Часть кода:

```
def parser(url):
data = []

for page in range(1, 3000):
    print(page)

    PRODUCT_URL = url+f"?p={page}"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(PRODUCT_URL)
    sleep(3)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='product details product-item-details')
```

где я вместо url - подставляю необходимую ссылку для ее парсера.

Вопрос в том: как заменить в данном случае `range(1, 3000)` ,чтобы парсер прекращал идти по страницам, на которых уже нет необходимых данных, и корректно прекращал свою работу.

Comment: Для получения ответа хотя бы ссылку на ресурс который пытаетесь парсить дайте. А если добавите свой код в вопрос это будет не только превосходно, но еще и соответствовать правилам ресурса, на котором Вы размещаете вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо @Namerek Добавил часть кода :)

Comment: Вот скажите, каким образом без ссылки на сайт или исходника страницы люди желающие Вам помочь должны догадаться как выглядит тэг пагинации который необходимо обработать для выяснения средств перехода по страницам? Кроме того, как я понял из правок вопроса, проблема была, с тем чтобы сохранить данные на несколько таблиц одного файла excel через pandas

Comment: Если следовать тому способу перехода по страницам который используете вы, то логично предположить, что можно проверить `status code` и если он отличается от 200 то прервать цикл. Либо проверить наличие необходимого элемента на странице и в случае его наличия/отсутствия прервать цикл...

Comment: Если items - пустой, то можно предположить, что товаров больше нет. Прерываем цикл.

Comment: @esergey Привет! Помогло "if not items: break". Спасибо!